# How can I make outside border of table different in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am trying to achieve this exact table:[Table wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4l97.jpg)

I have written this code in css stylesheet here:

```
table{
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color: white;
    color:#654321;
    border-collapse: collapse   ;
    border-style:outset;
    border-width:px;
    position: relative;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:DTCRoughM11,arial;

}
tr,th,td{
    padding:5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style:inset;
    border-collapse:separate;   
}
```

I am getting a result like this:
[Table i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ayxgf.jpg)

Basically, what I wanted to do is set outside border wider than inside borders with an inset border-style.

How Can I achieve that?

Comment: You need to set the border-width: 10px (something like) and you can set the color of each border differently.
I have seen the border-left,border-top color is different with border-right, border-bottom colors.
You can set them by using these css attributes.

border-bottom-color, border-left-color, border-top-color, border-right-color

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo. This line doesn't make sense:

```
 border-width:px;
```

Based on the screenshot, I think you probably want that to be maybe:

```
 border-width:3px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting a width on the border-width property of the table? In the code you have provided, there is no width defined...

border-width: 10px; for example.